# How do I write an ALTER index statement to include columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an index which has include. Now I added columns to my table and I want to add those columns in `INCLUDE`. How do I do that?

I am currently dropping the index and recreating them. Is there any other better way since the `ALTER` statement doesn't have any `INCLUDE` option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nope.

all you can do is recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about this one since I never have time to implement INCLUDES.  Just to much other busy work.

While the MSDN link for [ALTER INDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx) allows you to specify other attributes like fill factor, compression, etc.  The include is only used during a CREATE INDEX command.

Thus dropping and creating is your only solution.

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior (especially the section titled "*Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings*")